# Semaphore not working properly?

Tags: pthreads, semaphore

I have just started learning threads and semaphores.
I have created a simple program in C but its not working as expected.
Please look at the code and tell me where I am wrong?

Thanks in advance.

I am using Ubuntu 14.04.

Commands I am using

gcc -o foo th.c -lpthread

./foo

th.c is the name of my c file

on execution every time the program should output:

Thread 1

Thread 2

Hello threads!

But I am getting most of the times

Thread 2

Thread 1

Code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <semaphore.h>

void myFun1(void *ptr);
void myFun2(void *ptr);

char buf[24];
sem_t mutex;

int main(){

    pthread_t t1;
    pthread_t t2;

    char *msg1 = "Thread 1";
    char *msg2 = "Thread 2";

    sem_init(&mutex, 0, 1);

    printf("mutex 00 %d \n", mutex);    
    pthread_create(&t1, NULL, (void *) &myFun1, (void *) msg1);
    pthread_create(&t2, NULL, (void *) &myFun2, (void *) msg2);

    pthread_join(t1, NULL);
    pthread_join(t2, NULL);

    sem_destroy(&mutex);

    return 0;
}

void myFun1 (void *ptr) {

    char *msg = (char *)ptr;
    printf("%s\n", msg);

    sem_wait(&mutex);
    sprintf(buf, "%s", "Hello Threads!");
    sem_post(&mutex);

    pthread_exit(0);
}

void myFun2(void *ptr) {

    char *msg = (char *)ptr;
    printf("%s\n", msg);

    sem_wait(&mutex);
    printf("%s\n", buf);
    sem_post(&mutex);

    pthread_exit(0);
}
```

Comment: What do you expect? How can I say why it doesn't work the way you expect if you don't tell what you expect?

Comment: @gnesher729 - Sorry I forgot to update, Now I have updated the question.

Answer (score 1):

Your expectation is wrong.  Your program does not include any synchronisation to make the `t1` thread execute before the `t2` thread (or vice-versa), so either ordering is possible.

In the case where `t2` acquires the semaphore first, `buf` will still be an empty string and that is what will print.

What you need is for `t2` to wait until `t1` has filled the buffer.  You can do this by initialising the semaphore to 0, and only posting the semaphore after `buf` has been written to.  In `main()`:

```
sem_init(&mutex, 0, 0);
```

In `myFun1`:

```
void myFun1 (void *ptr) {

    char *msg = (char *)ptr;
    printf("%s\n", msg);

    sprintf(buf, "%s", "Hello Threads!");
    sem_post(&mutex);

    pthread_exit(0);
}
```

In `myFun2`:

```
void myFun2(void *ptr) {

    char *msg = (char *)ptr;
    printf("%s\n", msg);

    sem_wait(&mutex);
    printf("%s\n", buf);

    pthread_exit(0);
}
```

Now `t2` will only try to print `buf` after it has been initialised, regardless of whether `t2` or `t1` runs first.